# TFS(Git): More active pull request on same branch

Tags: git, tfs

I have a process question. Now Im planning the move from git/gerrit to TFS(Git) environment. Its very hard to me left the perfect functioning gerrit behind of us. :-(.
I start to checking the abilities of the TFS(Git) and I have a question. 
We would use feature-branches and during the tests I see I can not create more active pull requests on the same branch or I can not add extra file versions to the same pull request. Besides I always have to merge when the pull request finished.

How can I use the the following process:?

```
1. DEveloper A send a commit to a feature F branch
2. DEveloper B and DEveloper C review the commit
3. Developer A send fixes to the feature F branch
4. Developer B and C review it again
5. After everyone is extremely happy and the feature is finished feature F 
   will be merged
```

I could not find a soulution in TFS(Git) to expand the pull request in extra commits.

DO you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extra changesto the pull request. So it’s not necessary to have multiple active pull request on the same branch. This is because the new committed changes after the pull request will automatically add to the active pull request.

As the process you showed, after a pull request created for merge commit `a` from `featureX` into `featureF` branch, and then you make additional change on `featureX` branch during the above pull request still active. Now developer B and C review this pull request, they will find the additional change you made fir the second time also contain in the pull request.

Comment: Hello Marina. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: At the end of the day, we going to use the gerrit and the TFSGit will be the replication storage.